# How to expose a component's data to child components in a router context?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

My application is based on the [`vue-router` example](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/) where an all-encompassing component App has two child components `New` and `List` which are rendered in `<router-view></router-view>` depending on the route.

When `App` is mounted, it fetches some data which are available in its `data` structure as `users` (I refer to this data as `this.users` within `App`). I now need `New` and `List` to be aware of `users` (read-only, if it matters).

**My problem is that I do not know how to either make this object global (and therefore directly available to subcomponents), or pass it as `props` to the components.**

The [router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode) mentions how to essentially do this:

> When `props` is an object, this will be set as the component props
>   as-is. Useful for when the props are static.

This is supposed to be done when defining routes as

```
{path: '/list', component: List, props: users}
```

Now, following a [useful example](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/139/Vue-Router-Tutorial---Using-Vue's-Router-Library) the code above lives in a `router.js` (source at the bottom of this question) file which is imported in main.js and made part of the Vue instance:

```
import router from './router.js'

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**The data lives in `App`, the components are brought in in `router.js` - how can I pass it between `App` and `List`?**

---

```
// router.js

import Vue from "vue"
import Router from "vue-router"
import App from './App.vue'
import List from './List.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

const routes = [
    {path: '/list', component: List, props: users},
    {path: '*', redirect: '/list'}
]

export default new Router({
    routes: routes
})
```

Comment: if you just want to make it global, you could use vuex

Comment: @A.Lau: oh yes, thank you for pointing out the duplicate. I was not aware that one could pass items via `router-view`. While I love Vue, these are the kind of things I would love to see documented somewhere. Thanks again.

Comment: @WoJ the vue ecosystem documentation is pretty exceptional.  Here is the section on the router-view https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view

Comment: @Austio: yes, I agree. This is what brought me so easily to front end (amateur) development after years of (also amateur) backend (calculations, actually). It is just that the information is sometimes overwhelming. Thanks for the link (and thanks SO :))

Comment: Yeah agree, there is so much out there. Something that helped me a lot in vue community was joining their forum and then helping people there and also looking at solutions.  Think there is a link in that doc i shot over.